# Mock on the reflective setfiled name in mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Trying to do a real call to add method through calculator.

```
@Component
public class Calculator {

    @Autowired
    private Operations operations;

    public int calResults(int a, int b){
        int num = operations.opertaionMethod(a, b);
        return num  ;
    }
}

@Component
public class Operations {
@Autowired
private Subtraction sub;

@Autowired
private Addition add;

public int opertaionMethod(int a, int b){
    int num = 0;
    num = sub.subt(a, b);
    num = add.add(a, b); 
    return num;
}


}


@Component
public class Subtraction {


    public int subt(int a, int b){
        return a-b;
    }
}


@Component
public class Addition {


    public int add( int a , int b){
        return a+b;
    }
}


Junit:

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CalculatorTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private Calculator cal;

    @Spy
    private Operations op;

    @Mock
    private Addition add;

    @Mock
    private Subtraction sub;


    @Test
    public void test() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(op, "add", add);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(op, "sub", sub);
        Mockito.when(sub.subt(3, 1)).thenReturn(9);
        int n = cal.calResults(3, 5);
    }

}
```

Im trying to test add method in Add class, I want to do a real call instead of mock. whereas sub method i want to do a mock call. Using reflective i was able to set the fields in the operation class but without Mockito.when on sub object its making a real cal which i dont want. Using Mockito on sub im getting an unnecessary stub error while running unit test. Can any one please help me ?

Comment: If you have code that isn't working, then provide a [mcve] including error messages (within the question, not in comments) please.

Answer (score 1):

In simple cases like this the mocking framework does not seem to be making things any easier for you, a simple unit test would suffice:

```
public void test() {
    assertEqual(new Addition().add(2, 3), 5)
}
```

If you want to test the operations class I would suggest using the much simpler constructor injection technique instead of mockito:

```
public void test() {
    Addition addition = new Addition();
    Subtraction subtraction = new Subtraction();
    Operations ops = new Operations(addition, subtraction);

    assertEqual(ops.operationMethod(2, 3), 5);
}
```

The same idea would apply for the calculator class:

```
public void test() {
    Addition addition = new Addition();
    Subtraction subtraction = new Subtraction();

    Operations ops = new Operations(addition, subtraction);
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator(ops);

    assertEqual(calculator.calResults(2, 3), 5);
}
```

Comment: I dont to test individually, here i want to test through Calculator class

Comment: @user2514421 that's not what unit tests are supposed to do though.

Comment: Edited to test the `operationMethod` method, but @daniu is right, you want to keep your unit tests small.